# rmagick gem is not getting installed on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, redmine, rmagick

I am trying to install all ruby gems ion windows for redmine. Everytime I am getting below exception

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev-ruby\redmine>gem install rmagick
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
C:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=C:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:141:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENOENT)
from extconf.rb:141:in `configure_compile_options'
from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
from extconf.rb:548:in `new'
from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'
extconf failed, exit code 1
Gem files will remain installed in C:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/xampp/ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

rmagick is just a wrapper for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). `extconf.rb` is checking for the presence of ImageMagick by running `identify`, which is one of the programs provided by ImageMagick. It isn't finding it, hence the `No such file or directory` message.

You need to install ImageMagick and make sure that its executables are in your path.

Make sure that in the same place you run `gem install rmagick` you can also run `identify -version` successfully.

Comment: Thanks Max, I have already installed ImageMagick can you please also share how can I set the executables

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: Hello Max, environment variables are already set and I have installed ImageMagick at c:/ImageMagick, Still facing the same issue

Comment: Try running ImageMagick commands from the same shell doing the rmagick installation. It could be that whatever is doing the gem installation doesn't have the same path.

Comment: Thanks Max, can you please also tell me the commands i need to use for running imagmagick on shell.

Comment: The binaries I have are `animate,compare,composite,conjure,convert,display,identify,import,mogrify,montage,stream`.

Comment: Please can you complete your answer to explain how to solve the issue?

Comment: @SergioA. there are any number of reasons why ImageMagick might not be found by Ruby. It depends not only on how you installed ImageMagick, but how you installed Ruby. I can't give a single answer that will resolve the problem for everyone. Ask a separate question with more specific details and you might get help

Comment: Sorry @Max, I now understand all these tricky combinations needed to get RMagick ready to work. For anyone feeling a bit lost like i did, i recommend this link  which helped me solve my issue: https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/install-rmagick-gem-on-windows-7-8-10-imagemagick-6-9-4-q16-hdri-5492c3fef202

Answer (score 0):

This topic is kind of hard to solve, due to the problems with ImageMagick can be caused by any number of reasons.

For anyone feeling a bit lost like i did, i recommend this link which helped me solve my issue: https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/install-rmagick-gem-on-windows-7-8-10-imagemagick-6-9-4-q16-hdri-5492c3fef202